# JPA + Multiple ManyToOne Joins with same column

Tags: orm, mapping, jpa-2.0

The SchoolClass entity has a composite key made of schoolID, grade and section. 
The key in student entity is a composite of userName and schoolID. 
I am trying to add two foreign keys of student objects in my  SchoolClass. I want to use the same column schoolID in SchoolClass table in all the mappings, am wondering if this is the correct way to do it or not ?

```
@Entity
public class SchoolClass {

    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    @EmbeddedId
    private SchoolClassPK key;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="classRep1", referencedColumnName="userName", nullable = true),
        @JoinColumn(name="schoolID", referencedColumnName="schoolID", nullable = true),
    }) 
    private Student classRep1;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="classRep2", referencedColumnName="userName", nullable = true),
        @JoinColumn(name="schoolID", referencedColumnName="schoolID", nullable = true),
    }) 
    private Student classRep2;
......
}
```

Comment: Seems correct, are you having some issues? How does the generated schema (especially foreign keys) look like? Also I believe your design can be improved. Instead of two `ManyToOne` `classRep1/2` fields you should have `ManyToMany classReps`.

Comment: I want to restrict the number of classReps to 2. Can I manage that with the ManyToMany mapping you suggested ? I have used ManyToMany but from what I know it will be hard to control the number of students as ClassReps then.

Comment: You need to use MapsId annotations. But you should really consider making your life much simpler, and the code more efficient, by using single-column, autogenerated IDs for all your entities.

Comment: @JBNizet My student table basically has a userName and schoolID as the composite key.. would it be a better design to simply add a unique constraint on the combination of the two field and use the auto generated ID as the primary key ? That would make a lot of things easier for me.

Comment: Yes. That's what you should do. On all your entities. Composite keys are bad. Composite functional keys are even worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a better idea to simply remove composite keys in favor of an auto generated key on the entities involved.